# ortools routing solver the CVRPTW

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

How can I set the **Allow multiple vehicles to access a customer point** in CVRPTW ?
for example: customer 1 have 100 demands, and it can be visited by vehicle0 to delivery 20 and vehicle1 80.

sry, I don't konw how to set the constraints in routing solver! can you help me to solver this problem! thx!